# What is the probability of an element in a set being owned by a particular person when we know

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

### Premise

Lets say $S$ is the set of all unique items $s$ from which currently have been split off into $H_i$.

$H_1$
$H_2$
$H_3$
are sets that already contain $n$ specific elements $s$ from $S$. We don't know which ones they are. If an element is in $H_1$ then it can't be in $H_2$ or $H_3$.

$P_1$,
$P_2$, and
$P_3$
are subsets of $S$. Unlike $H_1$,...,$H_3$, these subsets can possibly overlap with each other.

$P_i$ contains all elements from $S$ that $H_i$ can possibly contain.

### Our Knowns

- For all $s$ ∈ $S$, we know which $P_i$ is it also in
- We know the size of each $H_i$
- We know the size of each $P_i$

### Question

Given $P_1$,
$P_2$, and
$P_3$ and the elements $s$ ∈ $S$ that they contain, and given the sizes of $H_1$,
$H_2$, and
$H_3$ how can we determine the probability for each $s$ ∈ $S$ of it belonging to $H_1$,
$H_2$, and
$H_3$.

### My understanding so far

I know that in cases where $P_i$ and $H_i$ are the same size, then $s$ ∈ $S$ have 100% chance of being in $H_i$. But in cases where the size of $P_i$ is larger than $H_i$ for i ∈ {1,2,3} and the size of the $H$ sets are different, how can I determine the probabilities?

$H_1$ size = 4 {2,4,15,13}
$H_2$ size = 5 {6,8,10,12,14}
$H_3$ size = 6 {1,3,5,7,9,11}

$P_1$ size = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,13,14,15}

$P_2$ size = {5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15}

$P_3$ size = {1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11}

While we're not supposed to know $H_i$, I put them there just for us, but we don't have that information.

We know $H_1$ is 4$C$11

We know $H_2$ is 5$C$10

We know $H_3$ is 6$C$9

In this example, how can I deduce each numbers' chance of belonging in H1-3, and how can I generalize that for all combination of hand sizes and $P_i$s.

Comment: You need to specify a probability rule about how probable it is for each element to appear in $P_{1,2,3}$. In my opinion the problem needs further specification.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. I’m not a math student or anything like that. Just programming a way to help me guess which dominoes players in a game mostly have.

In the game, people take turns placing dominoes. If they pass, that means they don’t have dominoes with the numbers currently in play.

I know my hand, but I don’t know the other three players’ hands. I do know S (the items not in my hand). 

P1-3 starts off as S, and as the game progresses, I can remove s from P depending on what’s been played and which ones they’ve passed on.